# OnStart() not listed as an Override method for android studio

Tags: android-studio

This may seem dumb and I might be missing something but I can not figure out why the onStart method is missing from my android studio shortcut list, yet I am able to do the override manually?

[image]

Comment: it does not show methods that youve already overrode

Comment: Wow, duh.  Thank you.